# Prevent content-scripts from running for a chrome extension with login when user is not authorised

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am working on a chrome extension that will extract keywords from a particular website(x) and search for those keywords in another website's(y) search page. I am using iframes to load the search page(of y) and it will be added as a modal/div to the  first page(x) ,this funcationality is added in content-scripts of chrome extension. But I want to make sure the website x is logged in and chrome extension has to be authenticated by SSO based on website X's login. Can anyone help me to prevent the content-script from injecting  div to the website x if website y is not authenticated in extensi. Find the code below that is used in content-script to inject the div

````
$("body").append("<div id = \"slider\" style=\"position: fixed;top: 0px;right: 0px;z-index: 9999;\"><div id=\"iframe\" style=\"position: fixed;top: 0px;right: 0px;z-index: 9999;\"><iframe style=\"border:1px solid #868686;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);\" src=\" https:abc.com/search \" width=580 HEIGHT=740></iframe></div><button id=\"button\">PushMe!</button></div>");```
````

Comment: so, the code you posted is the "script" that gets injected? How are we supposed to know, from that, how to determine if a user is logged in to X? are websites x and y just two websites known to you, i.e. x is a.b.c and y - d.e.f ... not something like x can be one of a list of sites, and y can also be one of many sites?

Comment: I have added these in my manifest.json so it ionjects script only on abc.com "content_scripts":
    [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https:abc.com/search"
             ] ,
            "js": ["jquery.min.js","content.js"]
        }
    ],```

Comment: still no explanation how code can determine if a person is logged in to some arbitrary site as far as we are concerned

Comment: I have to authenticate the login to website y based on the session cookie for website x , it will be based on enterprise SSO. But I have not worked on that part of login yet. SO I want to know  if the script injection can be pevented based on whether webiste y (in chrome extension) is authenticated or not

Comment: so do you need to know how to determine if website y is authenticated or not ... or do you already know how to determine that ... or can you only determine that after injecting the HTML?

Comment: I need to determine before injecting if the website is autheniticated so I can prevent injecting the scripts it is not authenticated. I donno how to do it